# function in a model that returns a boolean fails to return anything in a blade view if false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, boolean-operations

I have a function in a model that can return either `true` or `false`.

I use this function inside a view and first thing I discovered when I called it is

```
{{ Setting::isDesktop() }}
```

that it outputs 1 instead of `true` if I do that inside blade file. If I do `dd({{ Setting::isDesktop() }})` then it will print `true` or `false`.

Second thing that is giving me a problem is that, if the value is `false` then nothing is printed when doing this from blade file. I need something to be printed either `1/0` or `true/false`

Why does boolean get converted to number inside blade files but not controllers? How can I get something printed when isDesktop returns `false`? Right now it prints nothing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few methods you can achieve your requirement.
Here are couple of them,
1. Use Ternary operator like below,

```
{{ Setting::isDesktop() ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

2. Use var_export as shown below,

`{{ var_export(Setting::isDesktop()) }}`