# verify if any edit post radio button is checked when form is submited

Tags: php, laravel

I have this method where I pass some posts and also this `"isAnyPostButtonChecked"` to the view:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        ...
        $isAnyPostButtonChecked = false;
        $isAnyPostButtonChecked = $isAnyPostButtonChecked && (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $event->id);
        return view('posts.edit')
            ->with('posts', $post)
            ->with('anyPost', $isAnyPostButtonChecked);
    }
```

In the view I have a form and above the form I have `"{{$anyPost}}"` to  verify if any radio button is checked when the the form is submited. But it dont shows nothing with `"{{$anyPost}}"` when a radio button is selected and the form is submited. Do you know why?

```
   {{$anyPost}}
    <form id="editposts" method="post" 
      action="{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="form-check">
      <input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $post->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $post->id }}" id="{{$post->id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        {{$post->title}}
      </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input checked checked {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      Create post
    </label>
  </div>

  <!-- form fields, here is the name but are more like description,... -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Post title</label>
    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" name="title" id="tile">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="postupdate" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `->with('postss, $post)` - this should be `->with('posts, $post)`, no?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. I updated the question.

Comment: Your mistake is `->with('posts, $post)` should be `->with('posts', $post)`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: Do you got the value of `$isAnyPostButtonChecked` in your controller?

Comment: I have this: "$isAnyPostButtonChecked = $isAnyPostButtonChecked && (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $post->id);", its not that?

Comment: Yes, is it gives you any value?

Comment: With "        dd($isAnyPostButtonChecked);
" when page is accessed it appears "false". But like that the page appears blank.

Comment: It's only give you true false so it not print any value as you are trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It is not Printing in case of false you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683219/function-in-a-model-that-returns-a-boolean-fails-to-return-anything-in-a-blade-v)

```
{{ $anyPost ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

Before doing this, Please check by assigning other variable to $anyPost .

I could not post it as comment, due to my low reputation :D

Please let me know if not working.

Comment: Thanks, but when a edit post radio button is checked and the form is submited it also appears false. Do you know why?

Comment: To my understanding , you will get the value of checkbox in controller whatever the value of the checkbox is. As per my knowledge, If we check a checkbox and submit form it will be appeared in dd($request->all()) .  and if we dont check the checkbox, It will not be present in controller formvalues. So, you can check if checkbox is checked by isset($request['radiobutton']) . One thing more , I dont think it is good practice to generate multiple inputs with same name. 
you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute]

Answer (score 1):

Because $anyPost variable contains the false every time, so on the **false** value view show noting and if there would be **true** value then it will show 1 in view.

There is the issue in your condition please check it for **true** value.